# Css Parse errors

Tags: css

I have just validated, and these errors come up:

> Sorry! We found the following errors (2) URI : simple.css 320         Parse
>   Error  .tftable { font-size:100%;
>   color:#e0ece8; width:100%; border-width:.1em; border-color: #ffffff;
>   border-collapse: collapse; } 356      Parse Error  #wrapper {
>   background: #fff; color: #b6c5be; }

I've tried simply removing the stuff in  but that messes up all the colours on my page. Here is the code, line 320-356:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tftable {
font-size:100%;
color:#e0ece8;
width:100%;
border-width:.1em;
border-color: #ffffff;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tftable th {
font-size:105%;
background-color:#354640;
border-width: .1em;
padding: 1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #354640;
text-align:center;
border-bottom: solid .4em #6b806f;
}

.tftable tr {
background-color:#9db2a6;
}

.tftable td {
font-size:105%;
border-width: .1em;
padding: 0.8em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #6b806f;
}

.tftable tr:hover {
background-color:#b6c5be;
}

</style>
```

And Here's the whole thing:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| General Text Formatting
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

html, body {

    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;

    background: #b6c5be;
    color: #151816;
}

h1 { 
    font-family: Georgia, palatino, serif;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #151816;
    margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
    text-align:center;

}

h2 {
    font-size:120%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em 0 0.7em 0;
}
    h3 {
    font-size:120%;
font-family: Georgia, palatino, serif;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 1em 0 0.8em 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}


    h4 {
    font-size:110%;
    color: #e3f2ed;

}
        h5 {
    font-size:140%;
    color: #e3f2ed;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
}




p { 
    line-height: 150%; 
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;
    text-align:justify;
}

ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
    list-style: disc;
}

ol {
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
    list-style: decimal;
}

li {
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;
}

strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

em {
    font-style: italic;
}

blockquote {
    color: #000000;
    background: #9db2a6;
    padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 130%;
    border-bottom: solid .4em #6b806f;
    border-top: solid .4em #6b806f;
}




#footer { 

    /* 
    colours for text within the 
    footer division, ie <p id="footer"> 
    */
        padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    color: #e3f2ed;
    background-color: #354640;

            text-align:right;
}

.screen-reader-only {

    /*
    This is a special class used to prevent text from 
    being displayed on screen, while still making it visible to
    screen readers. Use this class if you want to add extra
    descritive text for visually impaired users, but don't want
    that description to be visible for other users. 

    For example:
    <p class="screen-reader-only">Special text for screen readers</p>
    */

    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}





/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Page Links
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

a:link { 
    color: #000000; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: none;

}

a:visited { 
    color: #000000;  
        font-style:italic;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover { 
    font-style:italic;
}

a:active { 
    color: #000000; 
}





/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Top Navigatin Links
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

TOP NAVIGATION LINKS
The following styles control the appearence 
of the top navigation links, eg. 
<a class="top-link" href="default.htm">Home</a>

*/

a.top-link {
    /* 
    these styles will apply to ALL links (:link, :visited, :hover and :active) unless    
    */
    display: block;
    padding: .7em 0 .7em 0;
    margin: 0 1em 0 2em;
    background: #9db2a6;
    color: #000000;

    padding: 0;
    line-height: 2.5em;
}

.top-link:link {
    /* styles for normal, unvisited links can be set here */
    /* these styles will override the defaults set for .top-link above */
    text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: solid .3em #9db2a6; 
}

.top-link:visited {  
    /* styles for links once visited can be changed here */
    /* these styles will override the defaults set for .top-link above */
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid .3em #9db2a6; 
}

    .top-link:hover { 
    /* styles for top links when a user hovers over it can be changed here */
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-bottom: solid .3em #6b806f; 
}

.top-link:active {  
    /* Styles for when the link is being clicked can be changed here */
}

.top-link.selected:link, .top-link.selected:visited {

    /* Sets the style of a link that has been selected (ie. has a class of selected)
       for example (note the additional class "selected"):
        <a class="top-link selected" href="content.htm">Content Page</a>
    */

    border-bottom: solid .3em #354640;
    cursor: default;
}





/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Footer Links
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Change these if you want your footer links to have a 
different style to other links

*/

#footer a:link {

    color: #e3f2ed;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#footer a:visited {

    color: #e3f2ed;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#footer a:hover {

    font-style:italic;
}

#footer a:active {

    color: #e3f2ed;
}





/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Header Colours
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

#header {   

        /*  
        Colours for <div id="header">
        See layout.css for layout and size properties
        */

    background: #00016c url(../images/headbit.gif) repeat-x top left;
    color: #354640;
}


#nav {

        /*  
        Colours for <ul id="nav"> 
        See layout.css for layout and size properties
        */

    background: #9db2a6;
    color: #000000;
}



<style type="text/css">
.tftable {
font-size:100%;
color:#e0ece8;
width:100%;
border-width:.1em;
border-color: #ffffff;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tftable th {
font-size:105%;
background-color:#354640;
border-width: .1em;
padding: 1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #354640;
text-align:center;
border-bottom: solid .4em #6b806f;
}

.tftable tr {
background-color:#9db2a6;
}

.tftable td {
font-size:105%;
border-width: .1em;
padding: 0.8em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #6b806f;
}

.tftable tr:hover {
background-color:#b6c5be;
}

</style>



#wrapper {
    background: #fff;
     color: #b6c5be;
}





   /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Widget Box Colours
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Colour styles for widget boxes, ie <li class="widget">
See layout.css for layout and size properties

*/

.widget {
    background: #9DB2A6;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom: solid .4em #6b806f;

}

.widget-heading {
    color: #E3F2ED;
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #354640;
    border-bottom: solid .4em #6b806f;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you validate your CSS? I checked the sample you provided at W3C CSS validator and it validated fine with only 1 warning of: **.tftable th - Same color for background-color and border-color**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a style tag in there: Get rid of it.

```
.tftable tr:hover {
background-color:#b6c5be;
}

</style>

#wrapper {
    background: #fff;
     color: #b6c5be;
}
```

Other than that, your CSS seems fine.

Comment: Just deleting it messed up the colours. When I also deleted the #wrapper, everything got fixed. Strange. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I don't what CSS parser, you are using.  It seems to valid, which I have tested using [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator).

No error but with one warning says,

> **`.tftable th`** Same color for background-color and border-color

Comment: That's just a chunk of it. I used w3c validator too. 
This is the whole thing